Sublime Text after build 4186 unable to insert tab
After Sublime Text updated to build 4186 there is a problem - unable to insert tabulation by pressing Tab.
It started to work really weird for me:

if cursor on start line Tab is working
if cursor after any alphabet charcter Tab is not working. In this case only shift + tab working
if cursor after space Tab is working

Previously, before build 4186, a tabulation character was inserted in any case when the Tab was pressed
My overrided settings:
{
    "auto_complete": false,
    "only_show_lsp_completions": false,
    "auto_complete_include_snippets_when_typing": false,
    "tab_completion": false,
    "font_size": 10,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false,
    "shift_tab_unindent": false,
    "use_tab_stops": true,
    "detect_indentation": false
}


Have you checked the release notes? Have you checked their bug tracker for similar reports? I'm honestly not seeing a programming here, since you're just using a text editor.

Have you tried entering sublime.log_commands() in the Sublime console following by pressing tab in those cases to see what command it is logging at the point where it doesn't work? Does it happen in every file regardless of type (text, python, html, etc) or just in a specific file. If you press tab twice in a row when it's not working, does that cause it to do something?
